# C / C++ includes & good practices?

Tags: c++, c

I have seen multiple times people include headers files subfolders in two ways

1. **#include "header.h"**
   and add *path/to/subfolder* in **include paths**.
2. **#include "path/to/subfolder/header.h"**
   and add only *root/folder* in **include paths.**

Not sure if this is just a matter of choice or there are any good bad practice rules around it.

Comment: Better to have one parent folder for all includes, add it in **include paths**, and then use relative paths for anything nested. This way you will avoid conflicts in case there are similarly named headers in different subfolders.

Comment: This is technically opinion-based, but #2 is better in general because you have less risk of conflicting headers in large projects.

Comment: I don't use paths in my `#include`, in preference to providing search directories to the compiler.  This allows the code to move with only changing the search directory.  Otherwise you'll have to modify every file that contains that directory.  Really bad and difficult when people use different named sandboxes.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer (hence this must be opinion-based) because you are allowed to do both.  You may want to 2 vs 1 but if a particular library you are using assumes 1 you will need to add it to the include path anyway.

Comment: These are all good points.. wondering what happens when two files with the same name slightly different contents (and lets say hence without warnings) are present in different include paths which one would be selected in that case? Guessing whichever is found first ?

Comment: @rahulb Most compilers search through include paths in the order provided to them and stop searching as soon as they find a matching header.

Comment: The style posted with quotes as `#include "header.h"` begins by looking in the current working directory for the header.

Comment: @WeatherVane That may be a common convention, but I do not believe it is specified by the standard.

Comment: @nielsen yes, in C18 **§6.10.2 Source file inclusion** it says *"The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner."* And then *"If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read `#include <h-char-sequence>`*

Answer (score 1):

An issue that can arise for case 1, but not case 2 is where you have two header files with the same name, but live in different directories, e.g.  `foo/utils.h` and `bar/utils.h`.  Using convention 2 from the outset eliminates this possibility.

Comment: If the old style `#ifndef UTILS_H` / `#define UTILS_H`... `#endif` is used and the name is derived from the file name, you will run into problems in both cases.

Comment: @Codo That's true, but really a different issue.  Ideally `foo/utils.h` would use something like `FOO_UTILS_H` and `bar/utils.h` would use `BAR_UTILS_H` to avoid such conflicts.

Comment: @Codo: a #pragma once instead of the #ifdef should solve this problem, but not the one the OP posed. In the world of SDKs that support a variety of platforms, this can be a real problem. CMake has features that can help, but there's no substitute for including pathnames in the include statement (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

In general use paths relative to the including file (= option 2.), if you don't see a risk of having to move the files relative to each other and use paths relative to a directory passed as compiler option otherwise.

The benefit of a path relative to the including file is that tools can pick up the included files outside of the context of a project/in the absence knowlege about include directories. This could come handy, if you just want to take a quick look at a source file without opening the whole corresponding project the IDE.

You may want to distinguish between both alternatives by using `#include <...>` to refer to files searched relative to a path passed as compiler option btw, since it's not always immediately obvious where to look for a included file as a human without the help of tools which may not always be available.

Answer (score 0):

If all the headers are part of your own code base, then it's not too important how you do it, since if a naming conflict arises you can simply rename one of the header files to fix the issue.

If you're including headers from third-party projects, OTOH, then you might not be able to (easily) rename those header files (at least not without forking the third-party project and maintaining your own hacked version from then on, which most people want to avoid).  In that scenario, it's best to have your #include-paths start at the level that contains the name of the third-party project (e.g. `#include "third_party_lib/utils/utils.h"`) so that the chances of a naming collision are greatly reduced (it could still happen if your project needs to use two libraries that both have the same name, but the chances of that are much smaller than the chances of two libraries both having a `utils.h`)